# Unable to install plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, redhat, rhel7

When I try to install any plugin on my Jenkins server, I get below error in the browser. I can see the list of `Available` plugins. Error occurs when I select any plugin and click on `Install without restart` or `Download now and install after restart`.

Error in Chrome:

```
This page isn’t working
xxxxxxx didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

xxxxxxx represents server name.

Error in Firefox:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

URL shown the browser address bar:

```
http://xxxxxxx:8080/pluginManager/install
```

What am I missing here?

My environment:

```
Server OS: RHEL7
Jenkins version: Jenkins ver. 2.121.1
JDK version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: looks like some connectivity issue here. Are you sitting behind any proxy? Is your system able to establish outbound connections over Internet and can accept responses too? You can check through telnet, doing curl to the above url etc.

Comment: Yes. Ingress/Egress working fine. No proxy.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, but only intermittently (Centos7, 2.131, OracleJDK1.8)

Answer (score 4):

Try using a different browser. I had the same issue. Was banging my head. But worked, when I tried to use a different browser.

Comment: Didn't work with Chrome or FF but it did with Safari.

Comment: Thank you so much, looks like my Chrome was way too obsolete, worked in Firefox.